# Какие есть стратегии одновременной работы из sync и async входными точками данных, как синхронизировать роботу над одной сущностью?

Tags: асинхронность

Например у меня есть sync(синхронный) REST ендпоинт и async(асинхронный) REST ендпоинт(который сохраняет данные и только через пару минут обрабатывает).

Может быть такое что:

1. пришел async запрос -> взял данные в обработку
2. пришел sync запрос и отработал успешно
3. запускается async джоба c данными из пункта 1

и тут вопрос: она должна упасть или sunc запрос не должен пройти
так как к нам пришел async запрос раньше?

Какие есть стратегии одновременной работы из sync и async?

UDP: сущность = анкета - с статусом (NEW, DONE, PROCESS, ERROR) и своим жизненным циклом (то есть сначала один человек ее заполняет потом, другой человек подтверждает что все правильно, а 3-й обновляет и навешивает цену причем все эти люди работают асинхронно с анкетой через сторонний сервис), а синхронно можно отменить эту анкету.

То есть у меня

1. пришло событие и мы только сохраняем в БД
2. выполняем отмену анкеты синхронно
3. должны обработать событие, но анкета неактуальная и падает обработка

Comment: Не совсем понимаю при чём тут вообще sync/async. А если у вас одновременно несколько синхронных запросов придут и будут выполняться с немного разной скоростью - у вас нигде логика не сломается? Должны быть какие-то thread safe очереди, транзакции и т.д., тогда не важно в каком порядке придут и обработаются запросы, данные всегда будут согласованы. Хотя я и не знаю, что за задачу вы решаете.

Comment: @CrazyElf думаю, автор имеет в виду различные моменты отправки HTTP-ответа. В синхронном случае сперва всё обрабатываем и только после завершения обработки отвечаем 200 OK, а в асинхронном сперва кладём задачу в очередь, сразу отвечаем 200 OK и только потом начинаем обрабатывать задачи из очереди

Comment: Тем не менее мне непонятен сам вопрос. Почему это вдруг sync запрос должен упасть? Что мешает sync и async джобам работать одновременно и независимо, никак не конфликтуя?

Comment: @andreymal И тем не менее внутри самой обработки может быть довольно разная логика и гарантии, что запрос, который начал обрабатываться раньше, раньше и закончится, никакой нет. И у какого запроса будут более свежие данные - тоже неизвестно. Поэтому если проблема с синхронизацией в коде есть, то она может и при синхронных запросах проявиться.

Comment: @andreymal да, правильно. async ответил ОК, но есть вероятность, что перед ним влазит sync запрос. Получается решения это при запросе sync проверять очередь нет ли у нас уже событий (хотя тут еще нюанс, что при некоторых событиях я не могу уже принять sync запрос )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Фундаментальная проблема не в том, что есть `sync`/`async`, а в том, что одновременно происходят два параллельных процесса, которые изменяют одни и те же данные. Т.е. точно такая же проблема возникнет, даже в случае если у вас все методы синхронные, но их могут вызывать несколько клиентов параллельно.

Есть три основные стратегии разрешения конфликтов при одновременных изменениях:

1. игнорировать конфликты. Грубо говоря, каждый процесс перезаписывает данные и то, что записали до него может потеряться.
2. запрещать изменение, если данные модифицированы параллельно. Один из вариантов - это в момент записи данных в хранилище (грубо говоря в БД), определять, что данные были параллельно изменены и завершать операцию с ошибкой.
3. делать слияние. Если при сохранении случился конфликт, то пробуем автоматически выполнить операцию заново с учетом текущего состояния данных, либо попросить пользователя разрешить конфликты.

Какую из этих стратегий использовать, зависит от сути операций. Для каждой операции нужно ответить на вопрос "а как правильно должна отработать операция, если данные которые она читает и модифицирует изменились параллельно?" Иногда это может потребовать  изменить API операции.

Например, для операции пополнение банковского счета, вместо использования общей операции типа `updateAcccount`, которая получает все поля счета, можно передать только суму пополнения (т.е. операция становится более сфокусированной `topUpAccount`). В таком случае операцию можно перезапустить автоматически при конфликте (т.е. использовать вариант 3). Понятно, что нужно перечитать данные и убедиться, что при новом изменении не случилось конфликта опять.

Answer (score 3):

Давайте я попробую перефразировать и ответить.
Забудьте про синхронностью и асинхронность.

Есть объект и его изменяют 2 процесса.

1. Первый процесс взял копию данных на обработку.
2. Второй процесс взял копию данных обработал и записал изменения.
3. Первый процесс записал изменения или нет изменения.

Что должно быть так или не так в третьем случае? Все зависит от логики. Возможные ситуации.

1. Кто последний тот и молодец. Процесс не проверяет изменяемые данные.
2. Кто успел тот молодец. Процесс проверяет данные перед сохранением и может получить данные устарели.

Оба варианта существует и применяются на практике повсеместно. Который правильно а который нет всё исходит из логики. К примеру. Вы изменяет данные учётной записи из 2х мест одновременно чисто гипотетически. Если вы меняете имя то логично что кто последний тот и молодец, а вот с паролем уже не совсем так.

Comment: Все верно (кроме грамматических неточностей:) ). Важно, что еще бывает и третий вариант. Тот кто выполняет действий вторым - сливает изменения т.е. в результате получаем результат обоих изменений. Это возможно, если, скажем, независимо меняются поля, которые не влияют друг на друга (т.е. их можно менять независимо и целостность не нарушается).

Comment: Мы ведь работаем с одним объектом? Результаты обоих если они в отдельных сущьностях, то проблемы работы сними а не с исходным объектом.

Comment: Я к тому что все зависит от логики а не от синхроносси

Comment: Пока топикстартер не уточнит что за данные и вообще в чём проблема - можно только гадать, какая стратегия его устроит. А то даже непонятно - записывается что-то или нет или речь только про обработку данных в нужной последовательности. Ну вот обработались данные - а дальше что? Непонятно.

Comment: То что (а)синхронность тут не имеет значения - это верно. Но для полноты, нужно бы добавить и третий вариант разруливания конфликтов, возникающих при одновременных изменениях.

Comment: Мне кажется, что это годный ответ, так как покрывает все случаи (если добавить вариант, который я упомянул).

Comment: Ответ такой что синхронность не важна тут. И работать с логикой автору. Ну и решать какой ему ответ принять